# What is the example of a continous state space and continous action space in Reinforcement learning with mathematical notation?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

> how are they represented in mathematical notation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discrete state space -> where states can have finite value. 
for eg  If there are only 3 types of weather: sunny, foggy, or rainy then this is analogous to a state-space that takes on three discrete values

Continous state space -> where states can have infinite value
For example, for a car, we might represent the state as (x,y,θ, x,˙ y,˙
˙θ), comprising its position (x,y); orientation θ; velocity in the x and y directions
x˙ and ˙y; and angular velocity ˙θ.

Hence, S = R^6, is an infinite set of states,
because there is an infinite number of possible positions and orientations
for the car